# XAML trigger template to set visibilty based on another element

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I have several StackPanels that change visibility based on ToggleButtons. The code below works if I replace `Tag` with `btn1` on the `DataTrigger`-lines.
How do I use the value of the `Tag` property?

```
<Window x:Class="MyTestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TestApp">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="panelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Tag, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Tag, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <WrapPanel>
        <ToggleButton Content="One" Name="btn1" />
        <ToggleButton Content="Two" Name="btn2" />

        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource panelStyle}" Tag="{Binding btn1}">
            <Label Content="Data to panel 1" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource panelStyle}" Tag="{Binding btn2}">
            <Label Content="Data to panel 2" />
        </StackPanel>

    </WrapPanel>

</Window>
```

This question is very similar, but I'm missing details on how to pass an element name.
[XAML - Generic textbox stylewith triggers / parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913730/xaml-generic-textbox-stylewith-triggers-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bindings are incorrect.

In your `DataTemplate` the bindings should be:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag.IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
   <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Here the `RelativeSource` with a mode of `Self` tells the binding engine that the object to bind against is object to which the style is being applied (e.g. your `StackPanel`). The `PropertyPath` of `Tag.IsChecked` tells the binding engine to look for a property called `IsChecked` from the object stored in `Tag`.

Finally the bindings in your `StackPanel` should be:

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource panelStyle}" Tag="{Binding ElementName=btn1}">
   <Label Content="Data to panel 1" />
</StackPanel>
```

Here `ElementName` creates a binding to another element in the logical tree. If you do not explicitly assign to any properties in a `Binding` as in your original example:

```
Tag="{Binding btn1}"
```

The value specified is assigned to the `Path` property. So this would be the same as:

```
Tag="{Binding Path=btn1}"
```

Also note, that using `Tag` is not considered best practice since it's type is of `object` and its use is unrestricted, and hence can take on any number of different meanings throughout your project (which often makes it difficult to understand, especially when used in `Templates` that are located far away from their actual use).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use Converter: set the visibility of StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel Visivility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btn1, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
  ...
</StackPanel>
```