# Generic style with specific trigger values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have several TextBlocks in my UserControl that I want to change to become Bold and have a Red font when a Property is triggered. The thing is that each of them are changed by different properties. I saw a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913730/xaml-generic-textbox-stylewith-triggers-parameters) with Tags, but couldn't quite get it to work for me. I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any solution that solved my problem.

My Style looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockTrigger" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="true">
      <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And this is the TextBlock I'm trying to use it on:

```
<TextBlock Name="TextBlock1" x:Uid="TextBlock1" Text="This text should become bold and Red"
Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTrigger}" Tag="{Binding Path=TriggerProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I added a button with a codebehind function that reads the Tag, and a breakpoint shows that Tag is set to true, but the text is still regular black.

TriggerProperty is set by a function call in the View Constructor, after InitializeComponent:

```
public MyWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  UpdateServerProperties();
}

public void UpdateServerProperties()
{
    //other code
    if(ServerValue == true)
    {
        TriggerProperty = true;
        OnPropertyChanged("TriggerProperty");
    }
}
```

It's a bit simplified, but the actual code is overly complicated, but results in the same thing. ServerValue gets a value, and I have confirmed TriggerProperty does get updated to true.

Comment: Do you set the TriggerProperty property dynamically? Do you implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `TriggerProperty` to `true` dynamically at runtime, the class where this property is defined should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the trigger to trigger.

If you set the `Tag` property to a hard-coded value of `true`, your sample markup should work as expected:

```
<TextBlock Name="TextBlock1" x:Uid="TextBlock1" Text="This text should become bold and Red"
           Style="{StaticResource TextBlockTrigger}" Tag="true"/>
```

You should also set the `Value` property to a typed `bool` value in your `Style`:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockTrigger" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
       xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Tag">
            <Trigger.Value>
                <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
            </Trigger.Value>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and have used the Property to trigger visiblity of other xaml blocks, like so: 
`<ContentControl x:Uid="WarnIcon"  Template="{StaticResource WarningIcon}" Visibility="{Binding Path=TriggerProperty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>`

Comment: using `Tag="true"` changes the text to red. But like I said, I added a Button that triggered a Codebehind function where I read the Tag in a breakpoint, and it got the value true from the binding, so I don't understand this.

Comment: How and where are you setting TriggerProperty? Please include some code that demonstrates this.

Comment: I have added simplification of it in the post. Actual code is too long for a SO post and just about all of it is irrelevant

Comment: Mike Strobel suggested the same, it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I saw that. +1.

Answer (score 2):

The `Tag` property has an `object` type.  Xaml has no way of knowing that `true` represents a `bool` value, so it just assumes you meant it to be a `string`.  Assuming you are setting `Tag` to a boolean value, your `Trigger` is evaluating `Equals(true, "true")`, so the condition fails.

Try using `{x:Static}` to point to some constant boolean value.  I keep a `KnownBoxes` class around for this sort of thing:

```
public static class KnownBoxes
{
    public static readonly object True = true;
    public static readonly object False = false;

    // ... more common values ...
}
```

These values are easily referenced from Xaml, e.g., `{x:Static ns:KnownBoxes.True}`.

Alternatively, you could use the element syntax:

```
<Trigger Property="Tag">
  <Trigger.Value>
    <s:Boolean xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">True</s:Boolean>
  </Trigger.Value>
  <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Trigger>
```

Or you could set `Tag` to the string `"true"`, though that may cause some confusion when someone else works on your code :).

Comment: using `s:Boolean` did the trick! Setting `Tag` to `"true"` was the second option, but I'd need to make a BooleanToStringConverter for that. This was much simpler, thanks!